# IMPORTXML Formula in Google Sheets

Tags: xml, web-scraping, google-sheets, xpath, google-sheets-formula

I'm having trouble pulling the financial data from 'Book Value Per Share' using Google Sheet's IMPORTXML function

```
=ImportXML("https://stockanalysis.com/stocks/bby/statistics/", [Xpath])
```

Xpath:

```
//*[@id="main"]/div[2]/div[2]/div[4]/table/tbody/tr[6]/td[1]/span
```

Answer (score -1):

You can't use import xml since the page is buit using javascript. You can parse the json contained in the web page

```
=bookValuePerShare(A1)
```

with custom function

```
function bookValuePerShare(url) {
  var source = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText()
  var jsonString = source.split('<script id="__NEXT_DATA__" type="application/json">')[1].split('</script>')[0]
  var data = JSON.parse(jsonString)
  result = data.props.pageProps.data.balance.data[5][2]
  return result
}
```

Comment: Nowadays the required data is available in the source code.